# How App Can Open Market &/or Browser in Kindle

Tags: android, android-activity, kindle-fire, kindle-kdk

I just want to know if there is an openURL command similar to handleOpenURL of Objc(iOS) in Kindle?

Actually, here's what I want to happen. If I can detect the Market app, i want to open Market and direct it to the app link i passed. If there's no app detected, I want to open the browser instead. Is this possible on Kindle? If yes, how do you do it?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To open the Market or Google Play App from within your app, your would use an intent alongwith the market:// protocol URI. For more info, refer to [Linking to your app](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningDetails)